# WebRTC SDP Codec Priority Reordering

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Can I change codec priority sdp answer via JavaScript? Maybe are there any settings? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You just have to change it as a string. But I wrote a [parser](https://github.com/beradrian/sdpparser), then I can manipulate the object and write it back as SDP.